# using tf.where() to select 3d tensor by 2d conditions & replacing elements in a 2d indices with keys and values

Tags: python, tensorflow, array-broadcasting

There are 2 questions in the title. I am confused by both questions because tensorflow is such a static programming language (I really want to go back to either pytorch or chainer).

I give 2 examples. please answer me in tensorflow codes or providing the relevant function links.

1) tf.where()

```
data0 = tf.zeros([2, 3, 4], dtype = tf.float32)
data1 = tf.ones([2, 3, 4], dtype = tf.float32)
cond = tf.constant([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]])
# cond.shape == (2, 3)
# tf.where() works for 1d condition with 2d data, 
# but not for 2d indices with 3d tensor
# currently, what I am doing is:
#    cond = tf.stack([cond] * 4, 2)
data = tf.where(cond > 0, data1, data0)
# data should be [[0., 1., 1.], [1., 0., 0.]]
```

(I don't know how to broadcast cond to 3d tensor)

2) change element in 2d tensor

```
# all dtype == tf.int64
t2d = tf.Variable([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
k, v = tf.constant([[0, 2], [1, 0]]), tf.constant([-2, -3])
# TODO: change values at positions k to v
# I cannot do [t2d.copy()[i] = j for i, j in k, v]
t3d == [[[0, 1, -2], [3, 4, 5]],
        [[0, 1, 2], [-3, 4, 5]]]
```

Thank you so much in advance. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are two quite different questions, and they should probably have been posted as such, but anyway.

1)

Yes, you need to manually broadcast all the inputs to [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where] if they are different. For what is worth, there is an (old) [open issue about it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9284), but so far implicit broadcasting it has not been implemented. You can use [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) like you suggest, although [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) would probably be more obvious (and may save memory, although I'm not sure how it is implemented really):

```
cond = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(cond, -1), (1, 1, 4))
```

Or simply with [`tf.broadcast_to`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to):

```
cond = tf.broadcast_to(tf.expand_dims(cond, -1), tf.shape(data1))
```

2)

This is one way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t2d = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
k, v = tf.constant([[0, 2], [1, 0]]), tf.constant([-2, -3])
# Tile t2d
n = tf.shape(k)[0]
t2d_tile = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(t2d, 0), (n, 1, 1))
# Add aditional coordinate to index
idx = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(tf.range(n), 1), k], axis=1)
# Make updates tensor
s = tf.shape(t2d_tile)
t2d_upd = tf.scatter_nd(idx, v, s)
# Make updates mask
upd_mask = tf.scatter_nd(idx, tf.ones_like(v, dtype=tf.bool), s)
# Make final tensor
t3d = tf.where(upd_mask, t2d_upd, t2d_tile)
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(t3d))
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0  1 -2]
  [ 3  4  5]]

 [[ 0  1  2]
  [-3  4  5]]]
```